pedantic understanding of set and function definitions (Tao Analysis I 3.5.10)
I want to check my understanding of the definition of a function, domain, co-domain and range.
I ask because the author of the textbook is normally very precise and this makes me doubt my own understanding.
The question arises as I do exercise 3.5.10 Tao Analysis I 4thed.

If $f:X \to Y$ is a function, define the graph of $f$ to be the subset of $X \times Y$ defined by $\{(x, f(x)) : x \in X\}$.
(i) Show that two functions $f:X \to Y$, $\tilde{f}:X \to Y$ are equal if and only if they have the same graph.
(ii) Conversely, if $G$ is any subset of $X \times Y$ with the property that for each $x \in X$, the set $\{ y \in Y : (x,y) \in G \}$ has exactly one element ($G$ obeys the vertical line test), show that there is exactly one function $f:X \to Y$ whose graph is equal to $G$.


Question 1:
For the first part (i) we show both inclusions:

Two functions are equal $\implies$ they have the same graph.
Two functions with the same graph $\implies$ they are equal.

For the second, without showing the detail here, we know the two functions have the same domain $X$, have the same mapping, and so have the same co-domain. Therefore we conclude the two functions are the same.
However, strictly speaking we know the two functions have the same range, also known as image. We can't know two function have the same co-domain simply because they have the same mapping. Is this correct?
Tao mentions in his book that sometimes we bend the rules of function equality if they share the same domain and mapping. Is this an example of that?

Question 2:
The author wants us to show that a function $f: X \to Y$ exists. However, the graph is based on a subset of $X \times Y$, and therefore the graph can only be for a function with a domain that is that specific subset of $X$. Therefore it can't be a function equal to $f: X \to Y$ because equal functions have the same domain.
Am I right, or am I misunderstanding something?

For Q2: Note that the property that $G$ has would guarantee that all of $X$ is the domain of $f$, because for each $x\in X$ there exists a $y\in Y$ with $(x,y)\in G$. In other words, $\pi_X(G) = X$ ($G$ projects onto $X$).

hi @MPW -  that is helpful. I'm new to "quantifiers" and that may be the cause of my confusion. In my mind I have a counter-example: imagine $G$ is a proper subset of $X \times Y$, that is not equal to it. And so the function $f$ for which $G$ is the graph has a domain that is a proper subset of $X$, not equal to $X$. Now, the exercise states "if $G$ is any subset", which to me suggests that all except one subset $G$ corresponds to a function where the domain is not $X$. I'd welcome your advice.

On the face of it, it seems like the domain could be a proper subset of $X$. BUT--the property that $G$ has actually prevents this. For every $x\in X$, there is a $y$ with $(x,y)\in G$. That says that you aren't leaving out any point of $X$. Specifically, suppose the domain of the function excludes some point $x_0$. But since $x_0\in X$, the property guarantees there is a $y_0$ with $(x_0,y_0)\in G$. Then $x_0$ is in the domain of the function, right? This contradicts the existence of a point of $X$ being excluded from the domain.

Hi @MPW - i read your reply last night and spent today thinking about it. I'm almost there I think. I agree that because G could be any subset, then the property applies to any $x \in X$. However, in the case that $G$ a proper subset, then the graph $G$ does exclude some $x$ such that $(x,y)$ are not in $G$. Thus the domain of the function represented by G is not the entire $X$. If you have the patience - and you have been very patient with my slow learning - I would welcome your advice again.

$G$ isn't just any subset -- it is a subset with the property "For any $x\in X$, ...". This property doesn't specify "for any $x\in G$", it explicitly says "for any $x\in X$". So, there it is.

@MPW - your last comment explained it perfectly!

One last comment: $G$ typically is indeed a proper subset -- but not of $X$, rather, of $X\times Y$. The set $X\times Y$ is pretty big compared to $X$, so $G$ can be a tiny part of $X\times Y$ and yet still cover all of $X$ in its list of "first coordinates". Think of what a small part of  the unit square consists of points in the graph of $y=x$ on $[0,1]$. Yet the projection down onto $[0,1]$ is the entire interval.
